# sqlite3_open_v2 treats folder name as file name in Xcode 14 which threw error in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, xcode14

In Xcode 13, this would throw an error `SQLError(code: 14, message: "unable to open database file")`. Turns out in Xcode 14, the last folder name (`UUID().uuidString`) is treated as file name and a new file gets created when calling open.

What changed in Xcode 14? And is it possible to configure `sqlite3_open_v2` so it will fail for a directory path instead of creating a file unexpectedly?

```
let temp = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
dbURL = temp.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString, isDirectory: true)
var connectionPointer: OpaquePointer?
let flags = SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX
let code = sqlite3_open_v2(dbURL.absoluteString, &connectionPointer, flags, nil)
if code != SQLITE_OK {
   throw SQLError.lastError(in: connectionPointer!)
}
```

Edit:
Tried using the `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` flag to see if it would enable a more rigorous check of the URL passed in. But it did not help.

Comment: But it’s not a directory. Just because you tell the URL that the path you are appending is a directory doesn’t make it a directory. And keep in mind that all you pass to SQLite is a string for the path, not a URL. So SQLite only sees an existing folder (the temp folder) and you tell it to create a database with a file name (the UUID).

Comment: But why was it not working this way in Xcode 13 then?